# ngMessages gives error first then resolves

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation which i dont think that i can reproduce easily on codepen but I will try to be as to the point as possible and any help or direction is appreciated.

This is the form excerpt (I stashed the classes to keep the example simpler/readable)

When the value of the textbox is changed the first time (when i enter something the first time) it gives out an `GroupsProfile.name.$error` error which causes class "has-error" to pop out. now if I change the value again (even to same text) I get all ok.

*This has nothing to do with ng-change or ng-click as I tried removing them and still same.*

```
  <div class="{{(GroupsProfile.name.$error && GroupsProfile.name.$touched) ? ' has-error ' : ''}}">
    <input type="text" ng-model="grp.name" name="name" required ng-change="check_grp()"/>
    <div ng-messages="GroupsProfile.name.$error" ng-if="GroupsProfile.name.$touched">
      <div ng-message="required">Group Name is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

with a little hard-work I have created a [pen](http://codepen.io/Rohithzr/pen/oxeZYQ)

to check for problem load the pen then write  letter in the field, and move out. u will see the error

to reproduce the error you will have to reload the page

Comment: try putting {{GroupProfile.name}} right above your div and see if required is true.

Comment: {{GroupsProfile.name.$error}} gives me required true, i tried that .... {{GroupsProfile.name}} placed anywhere kills angular

Comment: What is GroupsProfile?  Is this in an ng-form?

Comment: yes it is a Fomr name here: <form class="form-horizontal" name="GroupsProfile" ng-controller="grpsCtrl" method="POST" novalidate>

Comment: Try adding id="GroupsProfile" to your form and change it to ng-form.  See if that helps.  <ng-form class="form-horizontal" name="GroupsProfile" id="GroupsProfile" ng-controller="grpsCtrl" method="POST" novalidate>

Comment: sorry no effect at all

Comment: added a pen now. http://codepen.io/Rohithzr/pen/oxeZYQ

Comment: I don't see what the error is... it's working exactly as I'd expect it to.  Can you give me exact steps to re-produce what you think is an error?

Comment: open the pen, let it load, click on text box, write a character, press tab.... you will see red label now click and write again it will go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
<div class="{{(GroupsProfile.name.$error && GroupsProfile.name.$touched) ? ' has-error ' : ''}}">
```

Specifically, the GroupsProfile.name.$error.  This will evaluate to true unless $error is null.

At first, $error contains { required: true }.  As you start typing, this is replaced with {}.  {} is NOT null, so it applies your has-error class.

What you want instead is this:

```
<div class="{{(GroupsProfile.name.$error.required && GroupsProfile.name.$touched) ? ' has-error ' : ''}}">
```

This should fix your problem.

Also, you should be using the ng-class directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This fixed the problem for me.